# libboost_regex not compiling

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I'm trying to compile some regex inside my c++ code.

I've run `ln -s /usr/lib64/libboost_regex.so.1.53.0 /usr/lib/libboost_regex.so`
So that it is linked properly.

The command I'm running is: `g++-4.9 -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -I/usr/local/include/boost load_and_search.cpp -o bkSearch -L/usr/local/lib/ /usr/local/lib/libboost_serialization.a -lboost_regex`

I'm getting the following errors:

```
/tmp/ccrHjY7S.o: In function `boost::re_detail_106700::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::unwind_extra_block(bool)': load_and_search.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost16re_detail_10670012perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE18unwind_extra_blockEb[_ZN5boost16re_detail_10670012perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE18unwind_extra_blockEb]+0x2c): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106700::put_mem_block(void*)' /tmp/ccrHjY7S.o: In function `boost::re_detail_106700::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::find_imp()': load_and_search.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost16re_detail_10670012perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE8find_impEv[_ZN5boost16re_detail_10670012perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE8find_impEv]+0x8): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106700::get_mem_block()' load_and_search.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost16re_detail_10670012perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE8find_impEv[_ZN5boost16re_detail_10670012perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE8find_impEv]+0x142): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106700::verify_options(unsigned int, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)' load_and_search.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost16re_detail_10670012perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE8find_impEv[_ZN5boost16re_detail_10670012perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE8find_impEv]+0x183): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106700::put_mem_block(void*)' load_and_search.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost16re_detail_10670012perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE8find_impEv[_ZN5boost16re_detail_10670012perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE8find_impEv]+0x409): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106700::put_mem_block(void*)' /tmp/ccrHjY7S.o: In function `bool boost::regex_search<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > > >&, boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags,
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>)': load_and_search.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost12regex_searchIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS5_EEEcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEbT_SD_RNS_13match_resultsISD_T0_EERKNS_11basic_regexIT1_T2_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsESD_[_ZN5boost12regex_searchIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS5_EEEcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEbT_SD_RNS_13match_resultsISD_T0_EERKNS_11basic_regexIT1_T2_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsESD_]+0x10f): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106700::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> >
>::construct_init(boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)' /tmp/ccrHjY7S.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> boost::re_detail_106700::re_is_set_member<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> >, unsigned int>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>,
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, boost::re_detail_106700::re_set_long<unsigned int> const*, boost::re_detail_106700::regex_data<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, bool)': load_and_search.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost16re_detail_10670016re_is_set_memberIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEEcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEjEET_SB_SB_PKNS0_11re_set_longIT2_EERKNS0_10regex_dataIT0_T1_EEb[_ZN5boost16re_detail_10670016re_is_set_memberIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEEcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEjEET_SB_SB_PKNS0_11re_set_longIT2_EERKNS0_10regex_dataIT0_T1_EEb]+0x17e): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106700::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::transform_primary(char const*, char const*) const' load_and_search.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost16re_detail_10670016re_is_set_memberIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEEcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEjEET_SB_SB_PKNS0_11re_set_longIT2_EERKNS0_10regex_dataIT0_T1_EEb[_ZN5boost16re_detail_10670016re_is_set_memberIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEEcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEjEET_SB_SB_PKNS0_11re_set_longIT2_EERKNS0_10regex_dataIT0_T1_EEb]+0x2ee): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106700::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::transform(char const*, char const*) const' /tmp/ccrHjY7S.o: In function `void boost::re_detail_106700::raise_error<boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >
>(boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type)':                                  load_and_search.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost16re_detail_10670011raise_errorINS_20regex_traits_wrapperINS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEEEvRKT_NS_15regex_constants10error_typeE[_ZN5boost16re_detail_10670011raise_errorINS_20regex_traits_wrapperINS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEEEvRKT_NS_15regex_constants10error_typeE]+0x8d): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106700::get_default_error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)'                                                                                      load_and_search.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost16re_detail_10670011raise_errorINS_20regex_traits_wrapperINS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEEEvRKT_NS_15regex_constants10error_typeE[_ZN5boost16re_detail_10670011raise_errorINS_20regex_traits_wrapperINS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEEEvRKT_NS_15regex_constants10error_typeE]+0xc0): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106700::raise_runtime_error(std::runtime_error const&)'                                                               load_and_search.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost16re_detail_10670011raise_errorINS_20regex_traits_wrapperINS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEEEvRKT_NS_15regex_constants10error_typeE[_ZN5boost16re_detail_10670011raise_errorINS_20regex_traits_wrapperINS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEEEvRKT_NS_15regex_constants10error_typeE]+0xdb): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106700::get_default_error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)'                                                                                      /tmp/ccrHjY7S.o: In function `boost::re_detail_106700::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::extend_stack()':                    load_and_search.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost16re_detail_10670012perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE12extend_stackEv[_ZN5boost16re_detail_10670012perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE12extend_stackEv]+0x18): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106700::get_mem_block()'      collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status                             make: *** [tools] Error 1
```

I believe this still means that the compiler is having issues with the libboost_regex files

This is the code sample I'm trying to run:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <regex>
#include "BKTree.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <locale>

#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

using namespace std::chrono;

void prematch(std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > &parsedCsv, int &i, boost::regex &digitReg, boost::regex &flatNumReg)
{
    boost::regex digitReg ("^[^\\d]*(\\d+)");  
    boost::regex flatNumReg ("(?<=\\bflat\\s|\\bfl\\s|\\bapartment\\s)([a-z0-9]{1,})");  
    std::string add1 (parsedCsv[i][0]);
    boost::smatch digitMatch;       
    boost::smatch typeMatch;
    boost::regex_search (add1,digitMatch,digitReg);
    std::string add1String = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(parsedCsv[i][0]);
    boost::regex_search (add1,typeMatch,flatNumReg);
}
```

Could someone point out to me where I'm going wrong?
I'm only trying to use the boost lib so that I'll be able to use positive lookbacks.

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: No need to run in verbose mode, it's mostly noise.  The other message you show seems to be cut in the middle. Please post a [mcve]. This includes source code and a *full* copy of compiler messages.

Comment: @n.m. Changed it, hope this is better

Comment: The first thing you've done wrong is hitting your system with a sledhehammer, a.k.a. sudo. Try *gently* restoring it to its original state, then *ask stackowerflow* about the problem you tried to solve by installing stuff in /usr/local.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you compile and link against two different versions of boost:

1. One from `/usr/include/boost` and `/usr/lib64/`.
2. Another from `/usr/local/include/boost` and `/usr/local/lib`.

That may be the reason why you get linker errors.

---

> I've run `ln -s /usr/lib64/libboost_regex.so.1.53.0 /usr/lib/libboost_regex.so` So that it is linked properly.

`/usr` directories are managed by your system package manager, manually managing files there leads to troubles. Do not do that.

What probably happened is that you did not install `boost-devel` or `libboost-all-dev` or whatever boost development package is called in your system. That package provides headers and the libraries to link against. (That link you created manually may prevent the package from installing.)

Comment: Alright thanks for the help so far.

I've now done `yum install boost-devel` however it hasn't changed anything unfortunately. I'll look into undoing what I did with the ln -s command

Comment: @DanielLawton Remove those `-L/usr/local/...` and `-I/usr/local/...` options. Link `-lboost_serialization -lboost_regex`.

Comment: Command is now `g++-4.9 -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall load_and_search.cpp -o bkSearch -lboost_serialization -lboost_regex` .. Still no luck unfortunately, same errors

Comment: @DanielLawton That builds it for me. You probably messed up your `/usr` and/or `/usr/local` directories.

Comment: Could you provide any more detail as to what I could've done to my /usr or /usr/local directories?

Comment: @DanielLawton That would be way too much typing for me. The easiest is for you to reinstall your system (or install it in a VM), install boost development packages and try again.

Comment: That's alright, it's just because I know that the serialization library works fine and as intended, as I'm able to use `boost::archive::text_iarchive` later on in the program. Thanks anyway

Comment: @DanielLawton You are probably using the header-only part of boost::serialization and that is why it works.